# Big Query Dataflow Load to NULL partition

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using the apache beam Python SDK, I've set up a dataflow that writes to the individual partitions in a date partitioned table on Big Query. According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#comparing_partitioning_options) every date partitioned table has special `NULL` and `UNPARTITIONED` partitions. According to those docs I can write to the `UNPARTITIONED` partition by just setting my date far in the past or future, but how can I write to the `NULL` partition?

I'm trying to load data to a partition based off values in the data and sometimes the field is null. I'd rather write to the `NULL` partition than make up a date to use for nulls.

For reference, I write to date partitions doing something like this:

```
beam.io.Write(beam.io.BigQuerySink(table_id+'$20180925',
    project=project_id, dataset=dataset_id, schema=schema))
```

What do I need to replace `$20180925` with to write to `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *NULL* partition is only available in tables that are partitioned by a column in the data, not on ingestion time partitioned tables. If you are writing to a column partitioned table, you can simply not populate the value of that column in a particular row and use table_id (without any partition suffix) to write to the *NULL* partition.